# How to float or inline-block this the right way

Tags: html, css

One container with four or more divs inside that line up like a perfect puzzle and the last div fills out the remaining height..

the image illustrates how it should look like

[image]

where I am at: http://jsfiddle.net/meb9h3vx/

```css
.wrap {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.get2 {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>1</h1>
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>2</h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>3</h1>
    d
    <br>e
  </div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>4</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this -

1. remove `float` from both `.wrap` and `.get2`

   2. remove `text-align: center;` from `body` css
   3. add following css to `.get2` - `text-align: center; display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;`
   4. add `margin-left: -4px;` css to `.get2:nth-child(2) { }`
   5. and add `margin-left: -4px; margin-top: -17px;` css to `.get2:nth-child(4)`

Comment: Nice! thats what I just figured out

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox to the rescue with no dirty hacks:

```css
body {
    background:#000;
    color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px;
}
.wrap {
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height:auto;
}
.get2 {
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
}
.get2:nth-child(1) {
    background:red;
}
.get2:nth-child(2) {
    background:green;
}
.get2:nth-child(3) {
    background:yellow;
}
.get2:nth-child(4) {
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>1</h1>
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>2</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>3</h1>
    d
    <br>e</div>
  <div class="get2">
    <h1>4</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try by giving `min-height` as i am giving below

```
    .get2{
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
    min-height:120px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! So I inline-block the div and nth-child(2n) margin-left:-4px to get rid of the white-space and vertical-align:top and then the last part I added: padding-bottom: 99999px; margin-bottom: -99999px;  http://jsfiddle.net/p428b71y/1/

```
.wrap{
float:left;
background:#fff;
width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.get2:nth-child(2n){
margin-left:-4px;
}
.get2{
  vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
}
```

Comment: Rather than the `margin-left: -4` which is messy try removing the spaces/returns between your `get2` DIVs... sounds messy right? The trick I use to clean up `inline-block` elements is to use comments (`<!-- ... -->`) to remove the unwanted spaces/returns. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/p428b71y/2/)

Comment: You may want to read this as to why using 9999px (or in your case 99999px) is a bad thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971152/is-text-indent-9999px-a-bad-technique-for-replacing-text-with-images-and-what